# Magento test if a collection of products exist

Tags: php, eclipse, magento, collections, return

```
public function getAllProductById($id=0)
{
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('eq' => $id))
        ->joinTable(
            'cataloginventory_stock_item',
            'product_id=entity_id',
            array('quantite' => 'qty'),
            null,
            'left'
        )
        ->load()
    ;

    if ($products) {
        return $products;
    } else {
        return $products == null;
    }
}
```

The variable `$products` doesn't return null even when I use an id ($id) which is not set in Magento.

Comment: return $products == null; change this to return $products = null;

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code

```
if ($products) {
        return $products;
    } else {
        return $products == null;
    }
```

with

```
if ($products->count()) {
        return $products;
    } else {
        return $products = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `$products` with `$products->count()`. This will give you zero if there is no product in your collection. Like this below:

```
if ($products->count()) {
    return $products;
} else {
    return $products = null;
}
```